# External's HDD transfer speed permently slows down after transfer of specific files

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-transfer, usb-3

i bought a external USB 3.0 hdd (Western Digital 3ΤΒ), with independent power supply. Then i copied and pasted some files and the transfer speed was 70 mb/s to 93 mb/s. I have a folder about 100 gb with varius, small in size files, and i transfered them to the hard drive. The speed of the transfer was about 15 mb/s 30 mb/s, but after a little searching i read that this is normal when you transfer small size files. after this transfer the writing speed is starting at 55 mb/s and then slows down to 40-45 mb/s in large file (f.e. an 7gb iso file). Does any one now why is this happening. Is possible to damage the disk when i copied the large folder with small files?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the bad english.
ha
Any help would be appreciated.

Vaggelis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, and not an indication of any damage. You will not harm an HDD by putting lots of small files on it.

As you fill up an HDD, read and write times do increase. The first sectors on an HDD are the quickest to read and write to.

You may find [this article on disk structure](https://www.snia.org/education/storage_networking_primer/stor_devices/data_structure) useful in further understanding. Also, there's discussion of a [kernel issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12309) which may or may not be resolved, but seems to have a workaround by disabling swap.

Comment: hello @K7AAY and thanks for the answer, i use kali linux os (which is debian based) because i want to have some fun with my router. anyway i copied one more zip file of 100gb from kali and the speed was 55-45 mb/s. i tried it to a window 10 laptop and the speed was 80-105 mb/s so i think the problem is in kali os or in the bus.